# Transfer SSH private and public keys after reinstall

Tags: ssh, rsa, keys

I need to reinstall my system (debian) but I wonder if I could backup my pub and priv keys and then set them up on the new system.
Too many servers already have my pub key and I do not want to change it.

Will it work or is the pair of keys dependent of a system/machine/whatever...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your personal keys are independent of the system. All you need to do is make a copy of them and then put them back ensuring that you have the correct ownership and permissions on the files and directories.

Comment: Will accept it in 10mns (serverfault limitation)